# Sync conflict handling in Azure Mobile Services: ad hoc vs sync handler

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

When not using a "sync handler",  one needs to catch sync errors for push and pull.

PUSH:

Samples say to catch `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException`, `MobileServicePushFailedException` and `Exception`:

```
try {
  await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
}
catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex) {
  // ...push failed
  // ...do manual conflict resolution
}
catch (MobileServicePushFailedException ex) {
  // ...push failed
  // ...do manual conflict resolution
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  // ...some other failure
  }
```

PULL:

Samples say to catch `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` and `Exception`:

```
try {
  await syncTable.PullAsync("allitems", syncTable.CreateQuery());
}
catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex) {
  // ...pull failed
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  // ...some other failure
}
```

SYNC HANDLER:

Errors are processed in `.ExecuteTableOperationAsync()`. Samples say to catch 
`MobileServiceConflictException`, `MobileServicePreconditionFailedException` and `Exception`.

FINALLY A QUESTION(S):

I hope I covered all the possible exceptions types above.

*If I use a sync handler, does that mean I don't need to try-catch the push/pull/purge/etc. operations?* Samples I've seen are a little confusing as they include everything (ad hoc resolution and sync handler) in the same project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always place push/pull/etc. operations in a try/catch block.   There is always a risk that an Exception you haven't thought of (including the network going away, for example) will happen.

Comment: Also, many of the samples include a sync handler as an alternative way of doing conflict handling. (E.g., in https://github.com/lindydonna/xamarin-forms-offline-sync, the sync handler is not actually used the in the project). If you use a sync handler, you don't need to do conflict resolution in your exception block, but you DO need general exception handling.

Comment: Yes thanks guys, of course a general all-purpose catch is always warranted, but I didn't know where to do the conflict resolution.

Comment: For anyone else who's facing this issue on mobile, to solve the problem @AdrianHall mentioned regarding connectivity, you could use the cool [Connectivity library](http://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin). I use that to detect non-conflict NETWORK problems, which I believe will bubble up (down?) to the final `catch (Exception ex) { }`.

Comment: @lindydonna-msft Do you have a reference saying that we need a SyncHandler _or_ exception block exception handling and not both. I can't find any documentation that even says when the various exceptions the OP listed are raised.